# keyword stuffing in SEO

Tags: seo, keywords

i have a web shop, and on some of the pages some keyword in used a bit more then on the others.

For example: "hp toner" is used pretty much in the inscription of the product, in the alt tag, in the brand, and so on, an if i have let's say 100 of these products on the "HP PAGE", that means that "hp toner" is gonna show up at least 200 times more than some other random word...

but the keyword stuffing is not intentional here.. it's just that, the quantity of the product is bigger, and so is that word that describes it..

***Is that considered keyword stuffing in SEO terms?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keyword stuffing is when you *intentionally*, and *unnaturally*, placing keywords in your content for the *purpose of manipulating the search engine rankings*. If "hp toner" naturally appears often on your pages then that's fine. If you're cramming it in everywhere you can, including places where it obviously doesn't belong, then that's keyword stuffing.

As an aside, keyword stuffing is a waste of time nowadays because the search engines have both gotten good at detecting it and have devalued keyword density the point where it just doesn't make a significant difference anymore.

Comment: Yea, there are some pretty big sites out there (e.g. Amazon) that have hundreds or thousands of products with shared terms. I'm sure Google has ways to identify this type of keyword repetition. But you can also improve things for the search engines and your users by: 1.) using pagination so you don't have 100 products on one page; 2.) using synonyms in places so the text isn't so repetitive--the user probably doesn't need to be told a product is "HP toner" more than 2-3 times. And repetitive information is poor for user experience in general.