# Importance of frequency of keywords for SEO

Tags: seo, keywords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [keyword stuffing in SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/keyword-stuffing-in-seo)

I've seen a few posts on here and elsewhere that talk about the amount of unique keywords used, or aimed, for in a text. But how important is the frequency of keywords for SEO optimized copy, the higher the better? Is there a certain percentage to aim at?

For example, I currently have copy aimed for a specific keyword. The rate of this keyword is that it makes up 2% of all words. Is this too low? Too high? The higher the better?

Comment: Look into the Firefox Plugin "SEOQuake." It analyzes the site you're visiting currently (your site, for example) and tells you all the wonderful things on how to improve SEO, and there's even a section for "Keywords" and how many of them and the search frequency statistics. Very helpful.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question in a way that it explains how you see "frequency" being different from "amount" or the inferred "density"? Otherwise it will most likely be voted to be closed as duplicate

Comment: Thanks for the tip about SEOQuake. Mike, the amount of keywords would be the number of different keywords used (or aimed for). The frequency of a keyword is how many of the words are keywords in the text. 1%, 2%, 5%? Keyword 1 may make up 3% of the text and keyword 2 3.5% - is this difference meaningful? Do we strive for as high a percentage as possible, or is there point beyond which it simply doesn't matter anymore, if you can cram in another instance of a keyword?